# Is it worth reading The Elegant Universe?

Tags: string-theory, specific-reference

noob question here. I'm interested in reading The Elegant Universe by Brian Greene, but I've read some reviews that say the science has been discredited. I'm a total layman, has the science been discredited?

Comment: This is what we would consider a primarily opinion-based question, one in which the answer would depend on who is answering it with no real solution.

Comment: A suggestion: read it, and then for a second opinion, read some crackpot theory-of-everything from vixra.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of opinion, I would say: absolutely. In fact, *The Elegant Universe* was one of the books that really got me interested in theoretical physics. It uses examples that are easy for the layman to grasp and visualize, yet illustrate the essential properties of the physics. More objectively speaking, I would recommend looking at the table of contents and reading some excerpts. Here is the first chapter:

https://www.nytimes.com/books/first/g/greene-universe.html

It has also been adapted into an Emmy Award-winning program on the [PBS series NOVA](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/physics/elegant-universe.html). There are also some book reviews on Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/The-Elegant-Universe-Superstrings-Dimensions/dp/039333810X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/039333810X)